# validation of the table row

Tags: javascript, html, angular

I am just starting angular. i have a table and a button. on-click on the button a new row will get added to the table. each row consists of some dropdowns with required constraint. if the user doesn't fill mandatory dropdown then a appropriate message should display and enable addrow button if and only if that current row is valid.i tried the below code but it is not working. stackblitz link is given below and thanks in advance.

```html
      <tbody  class="form-group">
        <tr *ngFor="let row of rows">

          <td>    <input type="number" name="ques_temp" [(ngModel)]="noQuestion"> </td>
          
          <td>
            <select class="form-control" name="name" #name="ngModel"  required>
              
              <option [value]="" disabled selected>Select</option>
              <option *ngFor="let map of subject_maps" [value]="map._id" [selected]="map == subject_map">
                {{ map.subject_node.fullform }}</option>
            </select>
            <div *ngIf="name.invalid && name.touched)" class="alert alert-danger">
                <div *ngIf="name.errors.required">
                     Name is required.
                 </div>
              </div>
```

[stackblitz link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-rs6bkq)